# C++ Error C4700

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and need some help please! I am getting "error C4700 uninitialized local variable" on lines 23-26 for variables Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, EmpNum1, Pay1, EmpNum2, Pay2, EmpNum3, and Pay3 (in that order if it matters)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream PayFileIn;
    ofstream PayFileOut;
    PayFileIn.open("G:\\PayInFile.txt");                                        //change input file location per device
    PayFileOut.open("G:\\PayOutFile.txt");                                      //change input file location per device

    char Cat1, Cat2, Cat3;
    double Pay1, Pay2, Pay3;
    int EmpNum1, EmpNum2, EmpNum3;

    int AvgEmp = (Cat1 + Cat2 + Cat3) / 3;      //line 23                               //average number of total employees
    double AvgPay1 = Pay1 / EmpNum1;            //line 24                               //average pay for category 1
    double AvgPay2 = Pay2 / EmpNum2;            //line 25                               //average pay for category 2
    double AvgPay3 = Pay3 / EmpNum3;            //line 26                               //average pay for category 3
    double AvgPay4 = (Pay1 + Pay2 + Pay3) / (EmpNum1 + EmpNum2 + EmpNum3);      //average pay for total employees

    PayFileIn >> Cat1 >> Pay1 >> EmpNum1 >>
        Cat2 >> Pay2 >> EmpNum2 >>
        Cat3 >> Pay3 >> EmpNum3;

    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The average number of employees is:    " << AvgEmp << endl <<
        "The average pay for Category 1 is:     " << AvgPay1 << endl <<
        "The average pay for Category 2 is:     " << AvgPay2 << endl <<
        "The average pay for Category 3 is:     " << AvgPay3 << endl <<
        "The average pay for all employees is:  " << AvgPay4 << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message is very clear. You are using uninitialized variables.

```
// All uninitialized variables.
char Cat1, Cat2, Cat3;
double Pay1, Pay2, Pay3;
int EmpNum1, EmpNum2, EmpNum3;
```

What you need to do is move the lines

```
int AvgEmp = (Cat1 + Cat2 + Cat3) / 3;      //line 23                               //average number of total employees
double AvgPay1 = Pay1 / EmpNum1;            //line 24                               //average pay for category 1
double AvgPay2 = Pay2 / EmpNum2;            //line 25                               //average pay for category 2
double AvgPay3 = Pay3 / EmpNum3;            //line 26                               //average pay for category 3
double AvgPay4 = (Pay1 + Pay2 + Pay3) / (EmpNum1 + EmpNum2 + EmpNum3);      //average pay for total employees
```

after the lines that initialize the variables by reading into them from `PayFileIn`.

In other words, use:

```
char Cat1, Cat2, Cat3;
double Pay1, Pay2, Pay3;
int EmpNum1, EmpNum2, EmpNum3;

// Initialize the variables by reading into them from PayFileIn.
PayFileIn >> Cat1 >> Pay1 >> EmpNum1 >>
    Cat2 >> Pay2 >> EmpNum2 >>
    Cat3 >> Pay3 >> EmpNum3;

Now use them to compute other numbers.
int AvgEmp = (Cat1 + Cat2 + Cat3) / 3;      //line 23                               //average number of total employees
double AvgPay1 = Pay1 / EmpNum1;            //line 24                               //average pay for category 1
double AvgPay2 = Pay2 / EmpNum2;            //line 25                               //average pay for category 2
double AvgPay3 = Pay3 / EmpNum3;            //line 26                               //average pay for category 3
double AvgPay4 = (Pay1 + Pay2 + Pay3) / (EmpNum1 + EmpNum2 + EmpNum3);      //average pay for total employees
```

Comment: YEP. I thought I had tried that but i tried them up higher in the program. Thanks for the help! (like I said...I'm a noob to programming)

Answer (score 0):

You know those local variables it talks about?

**They're uninitialised!**

You are using them in a calculation but you have not yet given them a value.

Try moving the following line up above the calculations...  That way, when the code is executed in sequence, the stuff that puts values into your variables will actually happen first:

```
PayFileIn >> Cat1 >> Pay1 >> EmpNum1 >>
     Cat2 >> Pay2 >> EmpNum2 >>
     Cat3 >> Pay3 >> EmpNum3;
```